# PHP - evaluating param

Tags: php, eval, param

I have following code:

```
<?php
     $param = $_GET['param'];
     echo $param;
?>
```

when I use it like:

> mysite.com/test.php?param=2+2

or

> mysite.com/test.php?param="2+2"

it prints

> 2 2

not

> 4

I tried also eval - neither worked

Comment: Unless I'm not mistaking the "+" is used for URL encoding, so it would be translated to a %, which further translates to a white space. That's why you're getting 2 2.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is encoded as a space in `query strings`.  To have an actual addition sign in your string, you should use `%2B`.

However, it should be noted this will ***not*** perform the actual addition.  I do not believe it is possible to perform actual addition inside the `query string`.

Comment: soo how can I 'translate' it into +? I know it is possible, because e.g. you can test with it sql injection vulnerability - /index.php?id=2+2

Answer (score 0):

Now. I would like to stress to avoid using `eval` as if it's your answer, you're asking the wrong question. It's a very dangerous piece of work. It can create more problems than it's worth, as per the manual specifications on this function:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

So, everything that you wish to pass into eval should be screened against a very.. **Very** strict criteria, stripping out other  function calls and other possible malicious calls & ensure that 100% that what you are passing into eval is exactly as you need it. No more, no less.

A very basic scenario for your problem would be:

```
if (!isset($_GET['Param'])){
    $Append = urlencode("2+2");
    header("Location: index.php?Param=".$Append);
}

    $Code_To_Eval = '$Result = '.$_GET['Param'].';';
    eval($Code_To_Eval);
    echo $Result;
```

The first lines 1 through to 4 are only showing how to  correctly pass a character such a plus symbol, the other lines of code are working with the data string. & as @andreiP stated:

> Unless I'm not mistaking the "+" is used for URL encoding, so it would
>   be translated to a %, which further translates to a white space.
>   That's why you're getting 2 2

This is correct. It explains why you are getting your current output & please note using:

```
echo urldecode($_GET['Param']);
```

after encoding it will bring you back to your original output to which you want to avoid.

---

*I would highly suggest looking into an alternative before using what i've posted*

Comment: @PaulCrovella This is what I was referring too when I say a strict criteria. However, i'd rather stress that it is possible with using this method, but ***NOT*** To use `eval`